# Best way to check for well formed XML in Mule (3.4)

Tags: xml, mule

What is the current best approach for checking that an incoming XML message is well formed in Mule?

For example if I send badly formed (or non) XML to this choice then Mule throws an error and the flow stops:

```
<choice>
       <when expression="#[xpath('fn:count(//event/@publicID)') != 0]">
....
```

The error is like:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath    expression: "fn:count(//event/@publicID)"
at org.mule.module.xml.el.XPathFunction.call(XPathFunction.java:50)
```

And, alternatively, is there a way to catch and ignore this error in the flow?  I've tried the exception strategies as per the docs and got no where.

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have solved this by now, however there's a convenient filter in the mule xml module that may help:

```
<mulexml:is-xml-filter />
```

This filters out non/bad xml. You can use this with the message-filter to route to a dlq or throw an exception etc.

Also I can catch that exception as follows:

```
<choice-exception-strategy>
   <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException)]">
      <logger level="ERROR" message="not xml" />
   </catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, I had not found that.  Great answer and thanks for the catch example as well.  Nice!

Comment: @Ryan Is there a functionally equivalent way to do this in Mule 4 now that filters are no more?  I need to verify that inbound SOAP is valid XML, but the content changes every time, so I can't use a schema.